# Get model attributes values from CActiveDataProvider in Yii

Tags: php, yii, cgridview, cactivedataprovider

I have `zii.widgets.grid.CGridView` and I applied to it a `CActiveDataProvider` from different model, for example:

In the users model I used `zii.widgets.grid.CGridView` to display the articles that the user created, so when the user clicks on *view*, *update*, *delete* buttons, he should go to the articles controller actions, not to the users controller.

Here is my code:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'articles-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$ar,
    'filter'=>$articles,
    'columns'=>array(
                'title',
                'category',
                'display',
                'priority',
                'newsBanner',
                'idUser',
                'date',
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
                     'viewButtonUrl' =>"Yii::app()->createUrl('articles\view', array('id'=>'idUser'))"
        ),
    ),
));
```

the `idUser` that used in the url should be the same value as the `idUser` that used in the columns array in the widget, so how I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

you need to change

```
'viewButtonUrl' =>"Yii::app()->createUrl('articles\view', array('id'=>'idUser'))"
```

to

```
'viewButtonUrl' =>'Yii::app()->createUrl("articles/view", array("id"=>"$data->idUser"))'
```

**Note:-**

I have changed `idUser` to **$data->idUser**